# How to stop receiving intent TAG_DISCOVERED from the tag?

Tags: android, nfc

I have an application with several actitivities and the first activity accepts the intent `TAG_DISCOVERED`:

```
<activity android:name="com.iba.main.MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:launchMode="singleTask">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

All other activities are described in the AndroidManifest.xml as follows:

```
<activity android:name="com.iba.etd.EtdActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" />
```

But when EtdActivity is opened, intent `TAG_DISCOVERED` comes again, and the first activity, MainActivity, is being opened the second time. How to disable receiving that intent when application is already running?

Comment: try  android:launchMode="singleInstance"

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could register all your activities for the foreground dispatch system. This allows all your activities to receive and then discard/ignore all NFC discovery events.

To do this, you would register your activity with the NFC foreground dispatch system using the NfcAdapter's [`enableForegroundDispatch()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#enableForegroundDispatch%28android.app.Activity,%20android.app.PendingIntent,%20android.content.IntentFilter%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%5B%5D%29) method. This gives your current activity precedence in receiving NFC events over all other intent filters. See [Advanced NFC: Using the NFC Foreground Dispatch System](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc.html#foreground-dispatch) on how to do this registration.

Once you registered for the foreground dispatch system, your activity will receive all NFC intents in its `onNewIntent()` method (or as a pending intent result depending on how you register). There, you can simply ignore these events.

Also note that you typically do **not** want to register for `TAG_DISCOVERED` in your AndroidManifest.xml. `TAG_DISCOVERED` is only meant as a fallback-mechanism that is only triggered if no other app registered for a specific tag. Instead you should try using either `NDEF_DISCOVERED` (if your tag contains NDEF structured data) or `TECH_DISCOVERED` (to register for specific tag technologies).

Comment: Thanks, I supposed that this can be done in such a way, but hoped that there was way to make it in a more general manner (not in every Activity, but may be in AndroidManifest file).

Comment: No, each activity must specify (at runtime) that it will take special care of NFC events (handle/drop) otherwise Android will perform a system-wide default handling of the NFC event (dispatch to whatever activities are registered for the data types/technology types).